# How to send post input data ajax to controller?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to make an input search using ajax, I have tried it but it still fails I think the problem is when the value in ajax is not sent to the controller which results in the query like being left out, how do I fix this problem?

I using jquery-2.2.3, codeigniter 3

This is Js :

```
<script>
    $('#boxProfile').hide();
    $("#btnSearch").click(function(){
        var name = $("#inputNameNik").val();
        console.log(name);
        $.ajax({
            url     : '<?php echo base_url('index.php/Search/profile') ?>',
            type    : 'POST',
            data    : { post: name },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            beforeSend: function(e) {
                if(e && e.overrideMimeType) {
                    e.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                }
            },
            success: function(response){
                var html = '';
                var i;
                var no = 1;
                var success = 'Success';
                console.log(success);
                $.each(response, function(index, obj){
                    html += '<div class="box-body box-profile">'+
                                    '<img class="profile-user-img img-circle center" style="width: 160px; height:150px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="'+obj.foto+'" alt="User profile picture">'+
                                    '<hr>'+
                                    '<h2 class="profile-username text-center">'+obj.name+'</h2>'+
                                    '<p class="text-muted text-center">'+obj.nik+'</p> '+
                                    '<div class="small-box bg-red">'+
                                        '<div class="inner">'+
                                            '<h4 style="text-align:center;">Annual Leave in Year : </h4>'+
                                            '<h4 style="text-align:center;">Annual Leave in Year : </h4>'+
                                            '<h4 style="text-align:center;">Leave in Year : </h4>'+
                                            '<p style="text-align:center;">Balance Leave Now : </p>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                    '<button type="button" class="small-box btn btn-danger" style="margin:auto;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Import" >Click Detail <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></button>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>';
                });
                $('#boxProfile').html(html);
                $('#boxProfile').show();
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                var fail = 'Fail';
                console.log(fail);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is views :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNameNik" name="nameNik" placeholder="Search Nik / Name">
<span class="input-group-btn">
   <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="btnSearch"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</span>
```

This is controller :

```
public function profile() {
    $post = $this->input->post('inputNameNik');
    $query = $this->m_data->searchProfile($post);
    echo json_encode($query);
}
```

This is model :

```
public function searchProfile($where){
    $this->db->select('cuti.id_karyawan as cutiIdKaryawan, karyawan.foto, karyawan.nik, karyawan.name, cuti_before.id_karyawan as beforeIdKaryawan, cuti_before.tahun as beforeTahun, cuti_before.sisa_cuti as beforeCuti, cuti.tahun as tahunCuti, cuti.sisa_cuti as cutiSisa, cuti.saldo_cuti as cutiSaldo, tanggal, detail_cuti.keterangan, jmlh_hari, tgl_cuti_dari, tgl_cuti_sampai, cuti.tahun, DATEDIFF(karyawan.tmt_startwork, now()) as start');
    $this->db->from('karyawan');
    $this->db->join('cuti', 'cuti.id = karyawan.id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('cuti_before', 'cuti_before.id_karyawan = karyawan.id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('detail_cuti', 'detail_cuti.id_karyawan = karyawan.id', 'left');
    $this->db->like('karyawan.name', $where, 'both');
    $this->db->or_like('karyawan.nik', $where, 'both');
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct two things in the ajax call

If you are using single quotes `'` at the start of the URL then use double quotes inside.

```
url     : '<?php echo base_url("index.php/Search/profile") ?>',
```

Also, use single/double quotes to declare variable

```
data    : { 'post': name },
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove these lines from your ajax code

```
dataType: 'JSON',
            beforeSend: function(e) {
                if(e && e.overrideMimeType) {
                    e.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                }
            },
```

so in view file your updated code will look like below:

```
<script>
    $('#boxProfile').hide();
    $("#btnSearch").click(function(){
        var name = $("#inputNameNik").val();
        console.log(name);
        $.ajax({
            url     : '<?php echo base_url('index.php/Search/profile') ?>',
            type    : 'POST',
            data    : { name: name }, //change
            success: function(response){
                var html = '';
                var i;
                var no = 1;
                var success = 'Success';
                console.log(success);
                $.each(response, function(index, obj){
                    html += '<div class="box-body box-profile">'+
                                    '<img class="profile-user-img img-circle center" style="width: 160px; height:150px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="'+obj.foto+'" alt="User profile picture">'+
                                    '<hr>'+
                                    '<h2 class="profile-username text-center">'+obj.name+'</h2>'+
                                    '<p class="text-muted text-center">'+obj.nik+'</p> '+
                                    '<div class="small-box bg-red">'+
                                        '<div class="inner">'+
                                            '<h4 style="text-align:center;">Annual Leave in Year : </h4>'+
                                            '<h4 style="text-align:center;">Annual Leave in Year : </h4>'+
                                            '<h4 style="text-align:center;">Leave in Year : </h4>'+
                                            '<p style="text-align:center;">Balance Leave Now : </p>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                    '<button type="button" class="small-box btn btn-danger" style="margin:auto;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Import" >Click Detail <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></button>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>';
                });
                $('#boxProfile').html(html);
                $('#boxProfile').show();
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                var fail = 'Fail';
                console.log(fail);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And in Controller where you are getting form value use this code given below:

```
public function profile() {
    $post = $this->input->post('name');//it should be same as what you are sending from ajax field
    $query = $this->m_data->searchProfile($post);
    echo json_encode($query);
}
```

Please let me know if it'll work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you make the Ajax request you are sending `post` as the key for the input name but in your controller you are looking for `inputNameNik` as the key. This may be the cause you are not getting the input in the controller.

Although `inputNameNik` is the id of your html input, the PHP is unaware of this name, all it has is the variable that name you send through the post request.

Answer (score 0):

> you are passing `post` as key in `data:` instead of actual key which is name/id attribute `nameNik`/`inputNameNik`

```
 var inputNameNik = $("#inputNameNik").val();//changes
        console.log(name);
        $.ajax({
            url     : '<?php echo base_url('index.php/Search/profile') ?>',
            type    : 'POST',
            data    : ({ inputNameNik: inputNameNik }),//changes
```

in Ajax`data :` you need to pass values as `key : value` format so in controller you can use key to get post value

> i.e if i pass `data: ({ nameNik: inputNameNik }),` then i will use this in controller like `$nameNik = $this->input->post('nameNik');`
>   so whenever you pass post data from ajax becarefull with `key` which you need to use in your controller to get value from `post`